# cucumber - wanted to execute same scenario multiple time with multiple set of data ( data will be different ) without scenario outline

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

wanted to execute below scenario multiple time with different set of user name and password without using scenario outline. As I am new to this world so need some guidance

Data source - excel file

Language - JAVA

```
     @login
     Scenario: Login with correct credential 
     Given open browser & enter user name and password
     When validate user credential
     Then application should open
     And Logout to application & close browser
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Scenario: Login with correct credential 
 Given open browser & enter user name and password
 And enter<superuser> in ....
 And enter<superUserPassword> in ....
 Then click "dadada" button
 And verify application should open
 And Logout to application & close browser
```

Examples:

```
|superuser    | superUserPassword    | 
|"superUser1" |"superPassword1"      |
|"superUser2" |"superPassword2"      |
|"superUser3" |"superPassword3"      |
```